# Do we know any more about Khan from Star Trek Into Darkness

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-into-darkness

In *Star Trek Into Darkness* we meet Khan and know that he is superior to humans in more or less every way, but where did he come from? Was he once human? Or a completely different race as he was discovered on a ship after they were exiled - but exiled from where and what was it that he did that caused him and the other to be exiled?

If he was human and was just experimented on to make him the way he is why was there no record of him before?

Comment: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Khan_Noonien_Singh_%28alternate_reality%29 http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Khan_Noonien_Singh_%28alternate_reality%29

Comment: Khan has an extensive back-story in both the original Star Trek series (notably the episode TOS: Space Seed) and his own film (Star Trek: The Wrath of Khan). I've downvoted because even the most glancing of research would have told you this. I've also voted to close because you're asking at least 5 questions about his back-story.

Comment: I've VTC'd for the reason @Richard has mentioned, as well as the fact that you're asking basically for his biography i.e. a *lot* of questions

Comment: Is the question, has Khan got a a somehow alternate backstory in the JJA universe? Who discovered the at-drift Botany Bay? That sort of thing. That's probably a better question; is it your intent? I ask because you specifically mention Into Darkness.

Answer (score 5):

## Yes we know a lot about Khan

I suggest you take a look at [this page](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Khan_Noonien_Singh_%28alternate_reality%29) which provides you with all the details you probably want to know and more.

In answer to each of your questions:

- **Where did he come from?**: Earth
- **Was he once human?**: He always *has* been a human!  He's just a genetically modified human (i.e. a human augment).  The aforementioned Memory Alpha page explains that he was a human, either explicitly genetically engineered or selectively bred to be vastly superior to your average human
- **Why was he exiled?**: Well, the above Memory Alpha page answers that pretty well too:

  > Considered genocidal tyrants who conquered and killed in the name of order, Khan and his kind were frozen in cryogenic sleep.

  and that page goes on to say that it was a **self-imposed exile**; when the rest of humanity rose up against him and his followers, he and his 'family' fled aboard a sleep ship.

Comment: The guy was straight trippin'